# there is a PYTHON wrapper for KONSOLE?

Tags: python, qt, console

hi
i want to make a [OmmWriter](http://www.ommwriter.com/) clone for my shell terminal.
in python with QT
there are some wrappers for Konsole, or something similar, or whatever?
some advice?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want a fullscreen terminal, then you can switch to a plain terminal (Ctrl Alt F1 in Ubuntu). If you want mood lighting and elevator music, well, that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [pyqonsole](http://www.logilab.org/2571/)?

Comment: ok thanks i download and it works quite well.
if some alternatives or whatever come in your mind let me know